# After updating to Android Studio 2.3 cannot resolve symbol GoogleAccountCredential

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating from Android Studio 2.2 to 2.3 the editor shows an error claiming that these classes cannot be resolved:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException;
```

Building still works which is strange. I'm using the Gradle default wrapper and project's `build.gradle` references:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Rolling back to Android Studio 2.2 didn't help. After rolling back *and* switching back to gradle 2.2.3 removed the "cannot resolve" error message.

Comment: Upgrading to Android Studio 2.3 *and* again reverting to gradle plugin 2.2.3  removed the "cannot resolve" error message.

Comment: Finally I made it by dropping the project's workspace (the error still ocurred with Android Studio 2.3.3 and gradle plugin 2.3.3). After cloning the git repository and creating a new project from it is working now like a charm.

Comment: Back again - the error returned to me :(

Answer (score 7):

I meet the same question these classes cannot be resolved after the Android studio updates from 2.2 to 2.3.

`import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;`

The Gradle plugin and Gradle version setting.
[image]

Try syncing the project, click Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files.
It fix my problem.
[image]

Comment: I tried this but it didn't help - sorry. Switching back to 2.2.3 is currently the only solution for me :(